# python - Getting requests response in gzip encoding. How to convert the data to the actual file?

Tags: python, gzip

I am trying to download the file through API. I was informed that API response is in gzip encoding. I have to convert this response to the actual file with text data in actual format. Please help me how to do that. Here is my code

```
import requests

response=requests.get(api_endpoint,headers={"Authorization":token_no} data=response.content
```

Data is having gzip encoded data. The data looks like this:

> �j7���8}��#���hT�Nj���C�MKJ�#]�Sy�{

how can I convert this to the actual text data? I almost searched in Stack overflow but nothing helped. I also tried gzip library in python but that throws error as OSError: Not a gzipped file (b'%P')

Thanks

Comment: `requests`' [FAQ](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/community/faq/) says "Requests automatically decompresses gzip-encoded responses", so your data may not be gzip-encoded. That's also what the gzip library says.

Comment: What specific type of data are you expecting?  If the API returns a binary file - like an image or a spreadsheet - the you will still see apparent garbage after unzipping.

Comment: snakecharmerb  - Yes. I need to download the PDF file and the binary file has data like the above. I got to know that it is gzip encoded and used gzip module but no hope.. I need to create the pdf file (or whatever the format is) from that binary file.... I tried reading the data as binary and write in binary using python but that not even helped.